# Volume of a bounded region

Tags: calculus, volume

How do you find the volume of a region bounded by $y=\sqrt{x}, y=x-2$ and $y=0$ when rotated around the $x$-axis?

Comment: solid of revolution

Comment: You should look at the wiki entries for [solid of revolution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solid_of_revolution) and  [Pappus's centroid theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pappus%27s_centroid_theorem).

Answer (score 4):

Here is the region you need to revolve about the $x$-axis:

[image]

Your volume integral will therefore be
$$V=\int_0^2 \pi(\sqrt{x})^2 \, dx+\int_2^4 \pi[(\sqrt{x})^2-(x-2)^2] \, dx.$$